# integrate $1/(1+a^2-2a\cos(\varphi))\,\mathrm{d}\varphi$ from $0$ to $2\,\pi$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

Evaluating the integral  $I = \displaystyle\int_0^{2\,\pi} \frac{1}{(1+a^2-2a\cos(\varphi))}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi$ might seem a little hard, but using the back substitution $z = e^{i\,t} \quad t\in [0\,2\pi] \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathrm{d}z = i\,e\,^{i\,t}\,\mathrm{d}\varphi \quad \Rightarrow\quad \dfrac{\mathrm{d}z}{i\,z} = \mathrm{d}\varphi\quad$ and the identity: $\cos(\varphi) = \dfrac{e^{i\,\varphi}+e^{-i\,\varphi}}{2}$ that Integral seems to simplify (also the boundaries turn to $\partial M$ again):

$$I = \int_{\partial M}\dfrac{1}{(1+a^2-a\,(z+\frac{1}{z}))}\,\frac{1}{i\,z}\,\mathrm{d}z = -i\,\int_{\partial M} \frac{1}{(z+z\,a^2-a\,z^2-a)}\,\mathrm{d}z$$

So far this looks right to me, but while determining the zeros for using the Residue theorem, peculiar things happen:

$$0 = z+z\,a^2-a\,z^2-a \quad = \quad z^2-\frac{z}{a}\,(1+a^2)+1 \quad \Rightarrow  \quad z = \dfrac{(1+a^2)}{2\,a}\pm \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{(1+a^2)}{2\,a}\right)-1}$$

I find it quite weird to deal with such a bulky term. So I wonder, if I made a mistake somewhere, since oftentimes the exercise are designed to have nice fraction within them.

Anyway, if I'd continue, calling $z_1 = \dfrac{(1+a^2)}{2\,a}+\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{(1+a^2)}{2\,a}\right)-1}$ and $z_2 = \dfrac{(1+a^2)}{2\,a}-\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{(1+a^2)}{2\,a}\right)-1}$

hence $\displaystyle I = -i\,\int_{\partial M}\dfrac{1}{(z-z_1)\,(z-z_2)}\,\mathrm{d}z$

then $\text{Res$(z_1)$}$ becomes really ugly since its $\dfrac{1}{z_1-z_2}$ respectively $\operatorname{Res}(z_2) =\dfrac{1}{z_2-z_1}$, giving a totals value of $I = 2\pi\,(\operatorname{Res}(z_1)+\operatorname{Res}(z_2))$. Again, formulating out it's quite frightening to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that$$\left(1+a^2-a\left(z+\frac1z\right)\right)z=z+a^2z-az^2\color{red}-a.$$And the roots of $z+a^2z-az^2-a$ are $a$ and $\frac1a$. So, yes, you do get nice fractions.

Comment: Okay, that are good news. Despite of some simple mistakes I have caused the quadratic formula should be right now. However I can't find a simplification, giving me those results. I never had thought a quadratic equation can surprise me like that.

Comment: @Leon your quadratic solution is incorrect. Check again.

Comment: Actually, also by completing the square this should be right: $z+a^2\,z-a\,z-a = z^2-\frac{z}{a}\,(1+a^2)-1 = \left(z-\dfrac{1+a^2}{2\,a}\right)^2-\left(\dfrac{1+a^2}{2\,a}\right)^2-1$. Setting this equal to $0$ brings the  nested solution: $z = \dfrac{(1+a^2)}{2\,a}\pm \sqrt{\left(\dfrac{(1+a^2)}{2\,a}\right)-1}$. I also checked by program this is a root. However, simplifying is a total different story. The program can't even handle it.

Comment: Never mind , I just was blundered.